# Save the output of bigquery in JSON from python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

How can I modify this script to be able to see/print some of the results and write the output in JSON :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


def query_stackoverflow(project_id="gwas-386212"):
    client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query(
        """
        WITH
  SNP_info AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier
  FROM
  `gwas-386212.gwas_dataset_1.SNPs_intergenic_vep_pha005199`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SNP_info
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier,
chr_id AS chr_id,
position AS position, 
ref_allele AS ref,
alt_allele AS alt,
most_severe_consequence AS most_severe_consequence, 
gene_id_any_distance AS gene_id_any_distance,
gene_id_any AS gene_id_any,
gene_id_prot_coding_distance AS gene_id_prot_coding_distance, 
gene_id_prot_coding AS gene_id_prot_coding
 FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.open_targets_genetics.variants`) variants
ON
  SNP_info.identifier = variants.identifier""" 
  )
results = client.query(query)

for row in results:
    title = row['identifier']
    identifier = row['identifier']
    #print(f'{identifier}')
```

This is just printing a column the intentifier. i want to save the resulted table in JSON format. The JSOn from the google cloud platform should look something like this:

```
[{
  "identifier": "rs62063022",
  "identifier_1": "rs62063022",
  "chr_id": "17",
  "position": "51134537",
  "ref": "T",
  "alt": "G",
  "most_severe_consequence": "intergenic_variant",
  "gene_id_any_distance": "13669",
  "gene_id_any": "ENSG00000008294",
  "gene_id_prot_coding_distance": "13669",
  "gene_id_prot_coding": "ENSG00000008294"
}, {
  "identifier": "rs12944420",
  "identifier_1": "rs12944420",
  "chr_id": "17",
  "position": "42640692",
  "ref": "T",
  "alt": "C",
  "most_severe_consequence": "intergenic_variant",
  "gene_id_any_distance": "18592",
  "gene_id_any": "ENSG00000037042",
  "gene_id_prot_coding_distance": "18592",
  "gene_id_prot_coding": "ENSG00000037042"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) documentation for further information.

```
records = [dict(row) for row in results]
out_file = open("bigquery_response.json", "w")
json.dump(records , out_file, indent = 6)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you that helps but i have an error: raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type QueryJob is not JSON serializable

Comment: Great that works. Is any way the JSON that is created to be separated for each record and not in one line output? Now it is correct but it looks like one line in txt editor

Comment: There must be a way to select what to print in JSON from the script ? for example if we want just the columns identifier_1, chr_id , most_severe_consequence and gene_id_any. How i will select them ?

Comment: It should be formatting the JSON when dumping as far as I know. Can you include the json file's content in the question?

Comment: Yes i included 2 records as it was download after the query in the platform

Comment: @user3683485 Updated my answer again. It should work as intented now.

Comment: I have one more question. this script works fine for a query with a table that is already uploaded in BigQuery cloud. In my case is the  `gwas-386212.gwas_dataset_1.SNPs_intergenic_vep_pha005199` , Is it possible to provide a data set directly from python script as input ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with BigQuery but the whole point of BigQuery is to upload your data and run queries on that data in the cloud, no? Again, I'm not familiar with it's capabilities.

Comment: Yes but at this point i need to upload the dataset manually in the cloud. If i have for example 10 different datasets and i want the result for each query it would be good to be able to read the data and upload them from the script ion the cloud instead of manually.